# Is a bad practice create splash screen in first scene of React Router?

Tags: react-native, splash-screen, react-native-router-flux

I need to create a animated splash screen in a React Native app.

Reading about this, I found the same response: "Splash Screens only allows static images and you have to create a secondary screen that contains the animation and call it before the launch screen."

If I have to create a secondary screen that holds the animation, I can do it in Router Scene of React Native.

Is it a bad practice?